# how to restore one day before deleted data in wordpress?

Tags: plugins, get-plugin-data

Yesterday i accidently deleted very important people page data ,is it possible to restore that data and it is not available in trash

Comment: Deleted data is **deleted** data, or you have a copy or you have nothing to do.

Comment: No actually I overwrite data and even not finding revision page written anywhere

Answer (score -1):

It depends on what you have.  You could try a revision of the page (right above the "update" button on the page/post edit page.

The other option is that you could contact your hosting provider and ask them to restore from one of their backups.

Comment: evolve theme is used by me in the site and I am not able to see revision page written anywhere

Comment: Theme has nothing to do with revisions.